# How to fix a segmentation fault when passing an array of int?

Tags: python, numpy, segmentation-fault, rust, ffi

I have a Rust (1.2) library and I want to use its functions from Python (3.4) using Rust's FFI. I'm on OSX 10.10 Yosemite.

Almost all my functions take a mutable slice reference as the input:

```
pub fn myfunction<T>(array: &mut [T]) { ... }
```

I then expose this function to be used outside of rust with:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn ffi_myfunction(array_pointer: *const libc::int8_t, n: libc::size_t) {
    assert!(!array_pointer.is_null());
    assert!(n != 0);
    let mut to_sort = unsafe {
        slice::from_raw_parts_mut(array_pointer as *mut i8, n as usize)
    };
    myfunction(&mut to_sort);
}
```

This works fine: using python's ctypes module I can call `ffi_myfunction()` with a numpy array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes
import numpy as np

rustlib = ctypes.CDLL("target/debug/libmylib.dylib")

array = np.arange(5, dtype=np.int8)

rustlib.ffi_myfunction(ctypes.c_void_p(array.ctypes.data), len(array))
```

I also have rust implementation with `libc::int16_t`, `libc::int32_t`, and `libc::int64_t` and I can call them with `np.int16`, `np.int32` and `np.int64`.

I have a second set of Rust functions that I want to call from Python. These functions are slightly different as they take a mutable reference to a vector (not to a slice):

```
pub fn myotherfunction<T>(array: &mut Vec<T>) { ... }
```

I then create my wrapper as such:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ffi_myotherfunction(array_pointer: *const libc::int8_t, n: libc::size_t) {
    assert!(!array_pointer.is_null());
    assert!(n != 0);
    let mut to_sort = unsafe {
        Vec::from_raw_parts(array_pointer as *mut i8, n as usize, n as usize)
    };
    myotherfunction(&mut to_sort);
}
```

Unfortunately I get a segmentation fault when calling `ffi_myotherfunction()` from Python.

After some investigation, I can say the following:

1. Adding a `println!()` macro anywhere in either `myotherfunction()` or `ffi_myotherfunction()` make the function to perform properly. The output is as expected.
2. The rust library segfaults for any integer size used (8, 16, 32 and 64 bits integers tried).
3. The segfault does not seems to come from `myotherfunction()` but from the call to `Vec::from_raw_parts()`. For example I can comment out the call to `myotherfunction()` from `ffi_myotherfunction()`, leaving only the unsafe block, and the segfault still happens.

So there seems to be a difference between `slice::from_raw_parts_mut()` and `Vec::from_raw_parts()`.

But I cannot understand what is causing that segfault. Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong? Could there be an issue with how numpy stores its data? Or maybe something about lifetime, borrows or any other rust concepts I'm not getting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only use `Vec::from_raw_parts` with data that has been allocated in Rust code with Rust’s allocators. Anything else is truly unsafe.

I expect that Python uses malloc, but Rust uses jemalloc. If jemalloc is instructed to free an address that was not allocated by jemalloc, it will, I believe, crash. Thus, if a vector is freed (i.e. it passes out of scope, its destructor is run) or if it needs to reallocate (e.g. if you push an element onto it), you will encounter a crash.

The first issue is thus that the `Vec` is having its destructor run; that could be amended by calling `std::mem::forget(to_sort)` when you’re done with it. The other issue, that any reallocation will crash, is much more dangerous; you have basically made it that you cannot safely access your vector mutably and must be *extremely* cautious in anything you do with it. Really, you should assume that *everything* on `Vec` will make a crash. You should use a `&mut [T]` instead, if what you want can be done with it.

Comment: So I should use `slice::from_raw_parts_mut()` instead of `Vec::from_raw_parts()`, is that it?